# Failed to set (fieldImage) user defined inspected property on (UITextField)

Tags: ios, swift4.1

Could you help me with this error ? I try to add icon to UITextFeild and it show error like this :

Failed to set (fieldImage) user defined inspected property on (UITextField)

Here is my code :

```
var errorImg =  UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30,height: 30))
errorImg.image = UIImage(named: "error")
errorImg.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.right
txtEmail.rightViewMode = .always
txtEmail.rightView = errorImg

txtPhone.rightViewMode = .always
txtPhone.rightView = errorImg
```

Please help . Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to set it in "User Defined Runtime Attributes"?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgipX.png ? Because that should be the reason of your error, but not the one in your code.

Comment: Yes , I never try User Defined Runtime Attributes. But I think that is problem with this code because when I delete 2 line of this code yes it okay......::::: 
txtPhone.rightViewMode = .always
txtPhone.rightView = errorImg